# How do I hide a div when it loses its focus?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Basically I am trying to implement a login such as that of the new twitter. When you click on Sign In a div pops up with the fields. Now when I click anywhere outside the div (div losing focus) then the div should disappear.

I have tried the technique mentioned at [How to blur the div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259716/how-to-blur-the-div-element)

The code is as follows:

```
$("body").click(function(evt) {
            
            if (evt.target.id !== 'loginDialog') {
                $("#loginDialog").hide();
            }
        });
```

The trouble with that is the `target.id` will not equal to `loginDialog` even if I click somewhere withing `loginDialog` say within a child div.

So the above is a good direction to proceed towards, but the solution is incomplete.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I have a hunch some event bubbling handling code will be required but never done that before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If moving your mouse outside is not enough and you want it to disappear only if the user clicks outside of it, here's a snippet that might help you.

```
$('body').click(function(evt) {
    if($(evt.target).parents('#loginDialog').length==0) {
        $('#loginDialog').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok , the approach is right, but I did a few tweaks. Instead of $(this) I used $(evt.target) as $(this) is always referenced by the body so its parent is html. Also the comparison I used is .length !=0 and hide the logindialog in the else condition.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think it through. Sorry. I fix it for subsequent visitors.

Answer (score 4):

Better to use jquery fancybox plugin for iframe http://fancybox.net/ in the **various example**

[UPDATE]::Sorry for stupid hypothetical code. check the working code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $(document).click(
            function (e){
                var blur = $('#blur');
                var position = $(blur).position();
                var height = $(blur).height();
                var width = $(blur).width();

                if((e.clientX > position.left && e.clientX < position.left + width) && 
                    (e.clientY > position.top && e.clientY < position.left + height)
                ){
                    alert(e.clientX+' '+e.clientY);

                }
                else{       
                    /*Hide the div*/                    
                        $('#blur').hide();
                    /*Hide the div*/

                }


            }
        )
    })
</script>
<div id="blur">Blur me</div>
```

Comment: the blur event is not fired for div's so that shall not work.

Comment: This is also a good approach, however pestaa's code is just a couple of lines of code so I let that be the answer. I have upvoted your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Not such a good practce but might work...

```
$('body').click(function(){
     $('#loginDialog').hide();     

});
$('#loginDialog').click(function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```