# searchbar style property issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a simple searchbar with default background color of dark.  On focus it will be white.  After I click the box, the color changes, but when I click outside of the box the color is still white.  When I click outside of the box, the color should be dark again.

**[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xqbHj/)**

**Javascript**

```
function searchbar()
{
searchbar=document.getElementById("searchbar");
searchbar.style.background="#fff";
}
```

**CSS**

```
#searchbar{
background: #666;
height: 25px;
width: 345px;
}
#search{
width: 300px; 
height: 25px;
float: left;
border: 0;
}
#searchicon{
width: 10px;
padding: 2px;
margin: 2px;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
}
#searchadv{
color: #000;
width: 10px;
padding: 2px;
margin: 2px;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
}
#search input[type="text"] {
background: #666;
height: 23px;
width: 295px;
border: 0;
}
#search input[type="text"]:focus {
background: #fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="searchbar" onclick="searchbar()">
            <div id="search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
            <div id="searchicon">
                <img src="img/search.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="searchadv">
                <img src="img/down-arrow.png" />
            </div>   
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes, because your code includes exactly one click handler which sets the colour permanently to white, you don't have another handler to set it back. However, [your CSS alone is enough to do this](http://jsfiddle.net/5Xbx8/) (at least in modern browsers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find out the problem is variable and function will not be same. When I have the change the the function name it work fine.
Again thank guys for responded to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" onblur="searchbaroff(this)" />
```

**JS**

```
function searchbaroff(obj)
{
    obj.style.background="#666";
}
```

Also You can do like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" onfocus="this.style.background='#fff'" onblur="this.style.background='#fff'" />
```

For input fields better use `onfocus` instead of `onclick` besause if you set focus in field using `Tab` key, `onclick` does not work, and `onfocus` work, besides work in both cases with click and set focus with `Tab` key

Comment: @krishnaTORQUE Hmm .. chances are you're doing something wrong. You have added my function in JS code? You made a field input as I wrote?

Comment: actually its working in text area only not in entire searchbar area.

Comment: Try use recommendation from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1259769/813069)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("blur", function() {
       alert("use here background="#666";");
 }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <div id="searchbar">
        <div id="search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
        <div id="searchicon">
            <img src="img/search.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="searchadv">
            <img src="img/down-arrow.png" />
        </div>   
    </div>`
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search input").click(function(){
        $("#searchbar").addClass("focus");
    });

    $("body").click(function(event){
        if (event.target !==  $("#search input")[0]){
            $("#searchbar").removeClass("focus");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#searchbar{
height: 25px;
width: 345px;
}

#searchbar *{
background: #666;
}

#searchbar.focus *{
background: #fff;
}

#search{
width: 300px; 
height: 25px;
float: left;
border: 0;
}
#searchicon{
width: 10px;
padding: 2px;
margin: 2px;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
}

#searchadv{
width: 10px;
padding: 2px;
margin: 2px;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
}

#search input[type="text"] {
height: 23px;
width: 295px;
border: 0;
}
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/766rC/1/). The idea is to add and remove a class (in this case is `focus`) and style on it. This would create a more maintainable code as separate styling from logic. Here is the sample styling:

```
#searchbar *{
background: #666;
}

#searchbar.focus *{
background: #fff;
}
```