# onBlur() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, onblur

I want the `<div>` with class `.shell-pop` to be closed if they click out of the element area. It appears not to fire though, and none of the logs or alerts go off either. I've looked around and everything appears right?

**jQuery**

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    updateCart();

    $(".shell").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".shell-pop").fadeIn(300, function () { $(this).focus(); });
    });

    $(".shell-pop").on('blur', function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(300);
        window.alert("work");
        console.log("works");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="options-area">
    <div class="options-popup shell-pop">
        <div class="swatches">
            <div class="colors-shell colors" id="green">
                <p class="prices-for-swatch">$14.23</p>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-shell colors" id="pink">
                <p class="prices-for-swatch">$7.23</p>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-shell colors" id="blue">
                <p class="prices-for-swatch">$11.25</p>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-shell colors" id="orange">
                <p class="prices-for-swatch">$10.23</p>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-shell colors" id="default-shell">
                <p class="prices-for-swatch">FREE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="colors-shell colors" id="exit">
                <img src="img/Silhouette-x.png" class="x-logo" alt="exit" />
                <p class="closeit">CLOSE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="shell square">
                <img src="img/controllers.png" class="item-icon" alt="controller-piece">
                <p class="name-of-item">Shell</p>
                <p id="shell_Price1" class="items-price">0.00</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: what is `.shell-pop`? blur event wont be fired if the element is not an input element

Comment: Shell-pop is a div contain more divs. A lot of the examples i have seen were working with divs, so I'm not sure why that would make it fail to fire.

Comment: `blur()` won't work on divs, I believe. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1259769/1231271

Comment: DOM Level 3 Specification says valid targets include both `Window` and `Element` - so a `div` element is a valid target for a `blur` event (and it works in the test I just ran in Firefox). https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-blur

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your `<div>` a [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

> The tabindex global attribute is an integer indicating if the element
>   can take input focus (is focusable), if it should participate to
>   sequential keyboard navigation, and if so, at what position.

Observe the following...

```
<div tabindex="-1"></div>
```

---

```
$('div').on('blur', function() {
    console.log('blurrr');
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/n5r4c46s/) - simple demo

Comment: This allows the element to receive focus, which means it is possible for the blur event to fire. A tabindex of `0` will also make the element keyboard-navigable.

Comment: @Sohnee this is true! Thanks, I included a link which explains the different values

Comment: Ah, i see. I saw that but assumed it was only for literal tabbing through a page. I shouldn't have assumed and done more research on it.

Answer (score 1):

Blur will only fire on form elements. You should consider a different approach. For example, you could watch for click events on .shell-pop and determine it's current state.
Like

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('.shell-pop')) {
        alert('focused');
    } else {
        alert('blured');
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, this is generally the preferred way to close an element that is not focusable when clicked outside the element etc.